# amplify -v doesn't return anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am trying to build a web-app and just installed the amplify cli using `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` with this response:

added 26 packages, and audited 27 packages in 19s

7 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

but when I run ANY amplify command it doesn't give me any response, no error code nothing. Just goes to a new line.

Comment: what does `which amplify` or `amplify configure` return?

Comment: `which amplify` returns /usr/local/bin/amplify. How do I change it to the correct path

Comment: you can check if `/usr/local/bin/amplify -v` works. If yes, add you need to update the path (`export PATH="/usr/local/bin/amplify:$PATH"`) this way you will be able to use `amply` command and not /usr/local/bin/amplify.

Comment: Add sudo before the command. That should fix it

Answer (score 8):

You have to install Rosetta.

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Just two days of research

Comment: you are the boss. you saved my life

Comment: Thank you very much, I was puzzling over this for a while. Given that Mac silicon has been the standard for quite a while now, shouldn't @aws provide at least a one-line message when an M1/M2 processor is detected?