# Amplify commands not returning anything

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have been working on a react-native project with AWS Amplify and it has been going smoothly, until today when my amplify commands in the terminal are not returning anything. The last thing I did was run amplify upgrade then ever since then, any commands I run such as amplify -v, amplify configure, amplify pull, etc. immediately finish and don't return anything, not even an error.

There was another similar post on stack overflow about this but my issue is a bit different. I will link that post underneath, but their issue was that Amplify was not working from the start and they had to install Rosetta.

Has anybody had an issue similar to mine that they fixed? I don't want to have to delete and then reinstall the amplify CLI so I am hoping there is a workaround.

[amplify -v doesn't return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966665/amplify-v-doesnt-return-anything)

Answer (score 0):

Add `sudo` before the command. That should fix it. i don't know why.

example: `sudo amplify -v`